# Content Deployment performance issues

Tags: 2010, content-deployment

I'm struggling with Content Deployment tool on SP 2010 in these days, because it is the only way, how to repair our [permission issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15910/cannot-add-user-to-sp-group-sp-2010), however, it brings a lot of another small headaches with it even none of known issues stopped us. I know, CD deploys things that are stored in the Content db only, so we need scripts for recycle bin, alerts, master pages, versions (the most ilogical thing, because export can handle it itself with the right parameter) and we finally solved most of those things by scripts, but I cannot believe, why is **sooo slooow**.

There is no CPU, disks, memory or network or DB issues, it is inside one mid-size farm, deployed from one SC to another with a lot of disk space on app. server, but it seems that the job stops from time to time. Even results based on the some content are different, at the end of the day. SC with 420 000 objects ran for 4 hours, SC with 280 000 objects running for almost 6 hours right now and it is hardly in the middle (4000 objects in 30 minutes, in average). I read a lot of articles between the jobs and some of them writes about tricks with search, indexing or timer services, but nothing brings any clear solution. We have big problems to make one SC in three days (friday and weekend, there is no free time-window because of worldiwide offices), but yes, it finaly solves our issue...

I have listed many things in this question what we tried. Something is missing? Thank you for ANY clue, I'm desperate.

P.S. also if you have any idea how to move in-progress workflows (also via script, tool or something else) or workflow history, I would be grateful too. It is the only thing, that we cannot resolve now.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with different Content Deployment solutions in the past and I must admit it is not a silver bullet but in 2010 it has improved a lot.

My first question is how have you configured Content Deployment paths and the jobs?  Are you using out of the box content deployment with schedules?

It seems that you Content Deployments are migrating a lot of Content between site collections, but I don't see a problem because the first Content deployment between two site collections might take ages to deploy the content but subsequent content deployments will be incremental and will likely to take less time (default is incremental). But, you can use PowerShell to ensure the parameters of Content Deployments paths ans Jobs are correct.

You can define a schedule on how often the content deployment should migrate the content. The minimum time that you can force a content deployment to run is 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes and yes, we tried deploy SCs via PowerShell or  GUI, with parameters or with matrix of default options and it is still the same "speed"

Comment: Could you please post the PowerShell commands which you used? I believe incremental content deployment doesn't take much time to migrate the content between site collections?

Comment: ... but as you can see, we don't need incremental jobs for this purpose, that's why I posted link to original problem called "prmission issue" with solution inside the page. We need one full job per one SC for permission reparation, no other (incremental) backups are planned in the future right now. We tried CD jobs for one SC two or three times before the final job (and count time, see if it helps or not for our case), but these are full too. Must be. I think you catch this problem from wrong side

Comment: No, I understood the whole situation after reading your last post about permissions. IMO, have you started considering RBS especially if majority of files (between CD migration) are larger than 1MB. In your case, the DB size seems large and it will further grow maybe because of binary large object (BLOB) data.By using RBS to externalize BLOBs stored in the content database, SQL Server and SharePoint Server can jointly manage the data integrity between the database records and the RBS external store on a per-database basis, as well your CD time may significantly decreases.

Comment: Read the white paper about RSB: http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/C/D/2CDF0F90-DA03-4D71-A395-F69F9CB61453/oit2010-whitepaper-storsimple-sharepoint2010-rbs.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the whitepaper, it is great, but I'm afraid, that move data from fast disk array to WFE disk is not a solution, that meets our business and security requirements. But, we discovered yesterday at night, that all our db's have "autogrowth" atribute set to 1 MB. When we set it to 256 MB, we can import 20 GB of data in 30 minutes, instead of 500 MB before.

Comment: But make sure that you follow MS documentation for autogrowth. Try to Configure growth increments of approximately one-eighth the size of your file. Using an example of a 50GB content database, you would configure an increment of just over 6GB which sounds sensible to me. Obviously the figure varies depending on the environment and usage figures: a heavy collaboration enterprise environment might benefit from a slightly larger increment. Some more insights: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801.aspx